# WordPress - Display only Parent Category posts not sub categories posts

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I have been struggling to extract the parent category posts from Wordpress. When i am trying to display the only parent category posts the wordpress query displaying the sub-categories posts as well.

How can omit the sub-category posts. please help!!..

```
<?
// Get the post ID
        $id = get_the_ID();         


        //get all the categories ( this function will return all categories for a post in an array)
        $category= get_the_category( $id );

        if ($category->category_parent == 0) {

        //extract the first category from the array
        $catID = $category[0]->cat_ID;

        //Assign the category ID into the query
        $verticalNavigationSwitcher = "cat=$catID&orderby=ID&order=ASC";
     }              


        $result = new WP_Query($verticalNavigationSwitcher);


                    //$featuredPosts->query('showposts=5&cat=3');
                    while ($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post(); 
        ?>


   <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></li>


  <?php 
            endwhile; 
            wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't post outcommented code in your question. That, and fix your code indentation (I'd be glad to, but not when it's hard to tell what is what).

Comment: what the wrong with the code? it will display the all the posts of the parent categories and subcategories..it is valid for every word-press installed.

Comment: Outcommented code and code indentation, not what your code actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this query:

```
$verticalNavigationSwitcher = "category__in=$catID&orderby=ID&order=ASC";
```